# Intellij Source code does not match the bytecode

Tags: maven, debugging, intellij-idea, remote-debugging

I'm facing the next issue when I try to debug my code remotely with intellij: `Source code does not match the bytecode.`

[image]

I don't have any problem with the classes which are part of the current project, but with the .class files from the .m2 folder, which are dependencies updated in the pom.xml with some code changes. I got this error always.

I tried with mvn clean install, I deleted the folders from the .m2 folder, also I invalidated the cache and restart and rebuild the project. Not pretty sure how can I fix this issue. I blocked for some time, any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: There are a lot of possible causes. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45807888/source-code-does-not-match-the-bytecode-use-idea-debug-jdbctemplate